# SetFocus to asp:TextBox within asp:Panel within asp:Content from content Page Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, panel, setfocus

I have an asp web page(login.aspx) that uses a master page (master.page).

I need to set focus to an `asp:textbox(TextBox1)` that is inside an `asp:Panel(Panel1)` on Login.aspx

I want to set focus to `TextBox1` on an `asp:Button` click event (or page load on login.aspx for testing, I've tried both).

I have tried the following solutions with no success:

- Page.SetFocus(TextBox1.ClientID);
- Page.SetFocus(TextBox1);
- Page.SetFocus(TextBox1.ClientID)
- TextBox1.Focus();
- TextBox Test = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("TextBox1");
- Test.Focus();

Answer (score 2):

When using ASP.NET AJAX I use the ScriptManager to set focus...

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(this.FirstNameTextBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably Microsoft's:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/498707/scriptmanager-setfocus-script-doesnt-work-properly-in-ie8-unless-you-choose-compatibility-mode

I'm having the same infuriating problem.

Or it could be:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1252014/2392110.aspx